# Error en el sintaxis de getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].nombre);?

Tags: c++

Me tira error en compilación en el siguiente código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TOTAL 1000

using namespace std;

struct Alumno
{
    string nombre[50];
    char apellido[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};

int Ingresar_Alumno (int &e)
    {
        FILE *Estudiante;
        Alumno vectoralumno[TOTAL];

        if (Estudiante=fopen("Estudiante.dat", "ab+"))
        {
                std::string name;
                cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: ";
                getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].nombre);

                cout << "ingrese el apellido del alumno: ";
                getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].apellido);

                cout << "ingrese legajo del alumno: ";
                getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].legajo);

                cout << "ingrese el DNI del alumno: ";
                getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].dni);

            fwrite(&vectoralumno[e],sizeof(Alumno),1,Estudiante);

            }
        fclose(Estudiante);
        e++;
    }
```

Lo mas probable es que este haciendo algo mal en el sintaxis. Anteriormente usaba `cin >> vectoralumno[e].nombre;`pero cuando ingresaba el nombre y la persona tenia dos nombres (Ej. Andres Osvaldo) me salteaba la opcion en de ingresar apellido

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta el error en el sintaxis que obtienes?

Comment: En cuanto al etiquetado... el código puede ser C++98 o C++11 pero no ambos porque en el momento en el que alguien ponga una característica propia de C++11 el código no será compatible con C++98

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster el error es que no compila. Empieza a compilar y cuando llega al primer getline tira error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].legajo);
```

`getline` es una función pensada para leer cadenas de texto... no números. Para leer enteros, caracteres sueltos, números decimales, etc tienes que seguir usando `cin::operator>>`:

```
std::cin >> vectoralumno[e].legajo;
```

El problema que te puedes encontrar en este caso es que `cin::operator>>` no elimina el salto de línea. Si realizas varias lecturas verás que el programa empieza a hacer cosas raras... la solución es limpiar el buffer de entrada antes del primer `getline`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
std::getline(cin, vectoralumno[e].nombre);
```

`numeric_limits` es una plantilla que se encuentra en la librería `limits`. Sirve para obtener el rango de valores admitido por un tipo dado (En C++ los tipos no tienen un rango de valores fijado por el estándar sino que dependen de la plataforma en la que se compile el código).

---

Edito:

Un error en el que no me había fijado:

```
struct Alumno
{
    string nombre[50]; // <<---
    char apellido[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};
```

ahí estás declarando un array de 50 cadenas. Si usas la clase `string` en vez de `char[]` tienes que ponerlo así:

```
struct Alumno
{
    string nombre;
    char apellido[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};
```

Comment: Cuando pongo getline(con,vectoralumno[e].nombre); me tira error en compilación.

Comment: @SalvaCastro porque es `cin`, no `con`

Comment: Tipie mal recién, en el código puse cin y no me compila

Comment: @SalvaCastro revisa la respuesta que he visto un error que había pasado por alto

Comment: Cambie el struct y puse el getline y ahora no me deja ingresar el nombre cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: "; getline(cin,vectoralumno[e].nombre); Quise poner cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max()); pero no se que valores poner y cuando trato de compilar tira error y me dice "error: 'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'" y "C:\Users\Salvaaa\Desktop\nose\1\main.cpp|25|error: expected primary-expression before 'int'|"

Comment: @SalvaCastro Ya te avise de que `numeric_limits` se encuentra en la librería `limits`. Te falta ese include